# How to replace a tag with another tag system-wide?

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

Say I have two tags, "Green", and "Green 1".

How do I replace all instances of the "Green 1" tag with the "Green" tag, across all files on my device?

Answer (score 1):

I've had two 'Green' tags, though with slightly different names for quite some time, so I thought I'd see if I could find a workaround.

Best I can come up with is in effect a find, add, remove.
Fortunately it turns out I'd only a few 'other Green' so it was quite quick, but you can almost see the Finder 'thinking' as it ticks through them all.

From Finder Prefs>Tags, make sure both are ticked & then drop both your 'Greens' into the favourites at the bottom, circled.  You can only have 5 at once, so others will be removed. You can re-add afterwards. Leave this window open, you'll be coming back to it.

[image]

Open a Finder window & select your 'to be deleted' tag in the sidebar, to list all the files tagged with it. Mine was called 'In Queue'

[image]

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  to Select All.
Right click & assign the **other** green tag to the files, so they now have **both** tags.
Give the Finder time to finish - you can see it adding the second green dot…

Then - right click again & remove your unwanted tag.

Everything is now tagged with the single, wanted, Green tag.

Go back to Finder prefs & you can delete the extra tag altogether.

Comment: It seems to depend on what mood imgur is in. Sometimes it preserves the transparency, others it turns it black. There seems to be no rhyme or reason. I've been doing it this way for years.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, I'm just afraid it won't list all my files :-)

Answer (score 0):

Click the green1 tag in sidebar and select all the files and right click on them. Go to Tags.. and add/remove.

If green1 is not in sidebar, go to Finder Preferences -> Tags, and Advanced to get it visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not that simple - "The name "Green" is already take, please choose a different name".

Comment: Indeed!  (char limit)

Comment: I added a method - which preserves the colour & tags them all with the single correct tag. The 'spare' can then be deleted without losing your place. I think any other method will get rid of the tag, but you then lose track of which files used that tag.

Comment: You not bashing? https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com

Comment: For only about 8 hours, GMT, so I'll get any initial hats 'overnight', for me. Same happens every year. That does remind me to swap my avatar to the version that can take hats… ;)

Comment: Drop secrets in the chatroom! ;p

Comment: Secrets are the same as last year afaik - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%EF%B8%8F-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F